# C# two Forms in one time are flickering, focus is switching

Tags: c#, winforms

I open two forms in one time, I see a problem that both forms are flickering and the focus is switching between both. Any idea what is wrong?

The both formw should be in different display, but I can reproduce this behavior in 4K monitor as well.
On this 4K display, the forms are a little covered and I see that form and formTwo are flickering. Every form want's to be on top.

In the formTwo is the web site which has an animation, when the formTwo has a focus. This animation is flickering like both forms windows.

```
form = new PresentationScreen("web", new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080)); 
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
formTwo.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
form.Left = 1920;
form.Top = 1080;
form.Show();

formTwo = new PresentationScreen("web", new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
formTwo.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
formTwo.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
formTwo.Show();
```

The PresentationScreen contains only one Panel with CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser:

```
public partial class PresentationScreen : Form {

    private Panel mWebPanel;
    ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
    private String mCurrentWeb;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            CreateParams handleParam = base.CreateParams;
            handleParam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
            return handleParam;
        }
    }

    public PresentationScreen(String type, String path, Rectangle resolution) {
        InitializeComponent();
        mWebPanel = new Panel();
        mWebPanel.Size = new Size(resolution.Width, resolution.Height);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) {
            Program.logError("[PresentationScreen] path is empty!");
            return;
        }

        if (String.Compare(type, "web") == 0) {
            mCurrentWeb = path;
            webPanel.Visible = true;
            Program.InitializeChromium();   //TODO vlastni object
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            chromeBrowser.MaximumSize = new Size(resolution.Width, resolution.Height);
            chromeBrowser.Load(mCurrentWeb);
            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            webPanel.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }

    public void loadWeb(String web) {
        mCurrentWeb = web;
        chromeBrowser.Load(web);
    }

    public void useWebScript(String script) {
        try {
            chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Program.logError("[PresentationScreen]: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using target framework .NET 4.6

Comment: I experienced the similar behavior when CefSharp browser was present in the form. Flickering, random white screens etc. Therefore I switched to another WebBrowser (EO WebBrowser) which is also built on Chromium, but is not doing this strange flickerings and white screens. It is paid, but you can try trial version

Comment: Thanks, I will check "how to stop flickering C# winforms".
Unfortunately, I can not use trial or paid software. It's for one company.